# A counting problem related to Parallelogram

Tags: combinatorics

There are $n$ distinct points in the plane, given by their integer coordinates. Find the number of parallelograms whose vertices lie on these points. In other words, find the number of $4$-element subsets of these points that can be written as $\{A,B,C,D\}$ such that $AB∥CD$, and $BC∥AD$. No four points are in a straight line.

For example, $n=6$ and the $6$ points are $(0,0),(2,0),(4,0),(1,1),(3,1),(5,1)$ the number of parallelograms is $5$. I can find out the number of parallelograms manually if $n$ is small but how can I find out the number of parallelograms if $n$ is large? Is there any efficient method? If so,what is the method? Please explain it in details.

Answer (score -2):

The following code maybe help you

```
//C++ code for counting the number of Parallelograms
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility> //pair
using namespace std;

int N, x[2002], y[2002];
map <pair<int, int>, int> cnt;
long long ans = 0;

int main()
{
    cin >> N;
    for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
        cin >> x[i] >> y[i];
    for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)
    for (int j = i + 1; j <= N; j++)
    {
        ans += cnt[make_pair(x[i] + x[j], y[i] + y[j])];
        cnt[make_pair(x[i] + x[j], y[i] + y[j])]++;
    }
    cout << ans;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code makes use of a function $make\_pair(a,b)$ which doesn't appear to be defined here. Also I think you missed the point of the question. Assuming $make\_pair$ creates a new point that wasn't what the OP asked. He asked to find parallelograms no create them.

Comment: @IanMiller He want to find the number of parallelograms and my code is for that purpose. I have just `include<utility>` library for `make_pair` function, but in visual studio, you don't need to include that lib.

Comment: That will work for you but for anyone else without that library is not going to be able to make use of this answer. Could you please include it in your answer.

Comment: @IanMiller I edited the code, BTW thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry that wasn't what I meant. Reading your code I have no idea what make_pair(a,b) does. Can you copy that function, from the library it is in, into the answer.

Comment: @IanMiller `make_pair` is just a [(somewhat) smart constructor for `std::pair`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270563/purpose-of-stdmake-pair).

Comment: Sorry, I'm approaching this know lots of Java and little C++. How does make_pair work with cnt. The code adds two points together in x[i]+x[j],y[i]+y[j] then does what? I don't see a comparison there to another point. and even if it does compare it won't find all parallelograms as its assuming (0,0) is a fourth corner. (At least that how I'm reading it.)